# Tangent Plane to the Surface $x^3y+2y^3z+3xz^3=16$ at the Point $(0,2,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find an equation for the tangent plane to the surface $x^3y+2y^3z+3xz^3=16$ at the point $(0,2,1)$.

I have a feeling that this includes partial derivatives in a way.

Comment: Something like $F'_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)(x-x_0)+F'_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)(y-y_0)+F'_z(x_0,y_0,z_0)(z-z_0)=0$

Comment: I did google `tangent plane equation`, e.g. it leads [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TangentPlanes.aspx).

Comment: The gradient of the left-hand side gives you a normal vector.

Comment: The point $(0;2;1)$ is not on the surface.

Comment: @Bernard how about now?

Comment: It's OK now,. Don't forget to change the title too.

Comment: @Bernard Okay I will. Could you help me here if you can?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by helping you here?

Comment: @Bernard Help me solve my question

Comment: The comment from Alexey Burdin or the answer from Emilio Novati give you the formula to be used, in two different notations. The answer from bigman explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$ f \equiv x^3y + 2y^3z + 3xz^3 $$

Recall $$ \nabla = \left(\begin{matrix}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} 
 \end{matrix}\right)$$

We apply the gradient operator to $f$ which will give us the normal vector at some $(x,y,z)$

$$\nabla f =  \left(\begin{matrix}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} 
 \end{matrix}\right) x^3y + 2y^3z + 3xz^3 $$

$$\nabla f =  \left(\begin{matrix}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[x^3y + 2y^3z + 3xz^3\right]  \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[x^3y + 2y^3z + 3xz^3\right]  \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left[x^3y + 2y^3z + 3xz^3\right]
 \end{matrix}\right)$$

$$\nabla f = \left(\begin{matrix}
  3x^2y + 3z^3  \\
  x^3+6y^2z  \\
  2y^3+9xz^2 
 \end{matrix}\right)$$

And evaluate it at $(0,2,1)$ to get the normal vector to be $ (3,24,16)$. Now we have a point on the plane and the normal we can write the plane as $$3x+24y+16z = 64$$

Comment: What does delta f mean?

Comment: That's not delta, it's the nabla symbol. Defined $ \nabla=(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}) $
Because we are applying it to a scalar field, it is getting us the gradient.

Comment: Sorry, but can you like write it out like how you did in the comment. I am new to this.

Comment: I will make an edit to see if I can explain it better.

Comment: Hope this makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Given a surface $f(x,y,x)=0$ the gradient at a point $P$ is the vector orthogonal to the surface, so the equation of the tangent plane in $P$ is:

$$
\langle \mbox{grad} f(x_P,y_P,z_P),(x-x_P,y-y_P,z-z_P) \rangle=0
$$

where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product.

Comment: This would imply all tangent planes pass through the origin…

Comment: Sorry, my stupid mistake, I edit..

Comment: In my opinion, it's nicer to write its as $\langle\operatorname{grad}f(x_P,y_P,z_P), (x,y,z)\rangle=\langle\operatorname{grad}f(x_P,y_P,z_P), (x_P,y_P,z_P)\rangle$.

Comment: @Bernard: I prefer the other form because I see immediately that the vectors $\vec x -\vec x_P$ are orthogonal to the gradient. But it's the same :)